# How to access data in Angular4 from other application on same server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular, codeigniter

I've an application which is built on Angular 1.x and Codeigniter now I want to convert it to Angular 4 but it's a bit huge application so I'm starting with single modules, for example, I've 3 pages :

Home
Profile
Settings

so I want to convert Profile part first in Angular 4

so I create a structure like it :

Root ->
Application
Assets (Angular 1.x and CSS, JS)
System
Angular4 (For profile section)

Whenever user clicks on profile I've to redirect him to site/Angular4/profile
it's working till now with test data but now I've the main problem I want to access some codes of Codeigniter, for example, SessionKey which I use to call API and Profile page requires authentication too.

It's like I'm about to run 2 separate application but CI+AngularJS & Angular4 but need to use some data of CI+AngularJS app in my Angular4 app.

Is there any solution for it? if possible by structure change also let me know I can do that as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.